# SectionList React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

As the natural property of **sectionList** Renders **Header** and a list of items in **Heterogenous** Listing:
Eg:

```
<SectionList
  sections={[ // heterogeneous rendering between sections
    {data: [...], renderItem: ...},
    {data: [...], renderItem: ...},
    {data: [...], renderItem: ...},
  ]}
/>
```

How do i render **SubHeaders** Below **Main Header** and *List the items* of **SubHeader** as well as the **MainHeader**?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListHeaderComponent prop for your main header. And you can use renderSectionHeader for your sections. And also just keep in mind if you don't want a sticky header stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html#listheadercomponent

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html#rendersectionheader

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html#stickysectionheadersenabled

Hope this will solve your problems.